# Analysis of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{\sin(xyz)} {x^2+y^2+z^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y,z)=\frac {\sin(xyz)} {x^2+y^2+z^2}$ or $0$ if $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$

The problem says the following:
a) Where is this function continuous, and
b) Where is it differentiable?

At a quick glance, the only point which might give problems is the origin point.

For (a), I did the following:

> *To prove that the limit of the first part of the function is 0 I used an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof of said limit.*
>   *If $0<|(x^2+y^2+z^2)|<\delta$ then $|\frac {\sin(xyz)} {x^2+y^2+z^2}|<\epsilon$*
>   *The inequalities I used are: $|\frac {\sin(xyz)} {x^2+y^2+z^2}|<|\frac {xyz} {x^2+y^2+z^2}|<|\frac {(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}}
> {x^2+y^2+z^2}|<|\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}|<\epsilon$,
>
>   so that if $\epsilon=\delta$, the limit is proven to exist and equal 0, so f is continuous in $R^3$*

And for (b) I used spherical coordinates:

$x=r\cos\theta \sin\varphi , y=r\cos\theta \sin\varphi , z=r\cos\varphi$
so the function is now $f(x,y,z)= \frac {\sin (r^3 \cos\theta \sin\theta \cos\varphi \sin^2\varphi)} {r^2}$

> *The differentiability condition is that, if f is to be differentiable
>   in a given point, f must tend to the limit faster than the distance
>   between the test point and the point where the function is being
>   evaluated. In this case, $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow (0,0,0)}\frac
>  {f(x,y,z)} {r} = 0$ must be true for f to be differentiable
>   everywhere.*
>
> *Substituting the function, this translates into $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow (0,0,0)}\frac {\sin (r^3 \cos\theta \sin\theta \cos\varphi \sin^2\varphi)} {r^3}$, but since r goes to 0, we can "take
>   out" the sine, and then the distances cancel out. What is left is
>   $\cos\theta \sin\theta \cos\varphi \sin^2\varphi$, which does not equal 0
>   unless you chose a path contained within one of the planes generated
>   by two cartesian axes (and so the limit does not exist at all), so f is differentiable everywhere but the origin.*

The question is, simply: What or where did I go wrong?

Many, many thanks in advance.

Comment: You didn't really go wrong, other than that you are being a little loose with the rigor. The observation that the directional derivatives depend on direction is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What you did in $a)$ is perfect. Now, I still write $f$ for it continuous extension over $\mathbb R^3$ by defining $f(0,0,0)=0$.

About question b), the intuition behind your calculus is that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0,0)$. Here is a way to see this.

First, you can check that the classical partial derivatives of $f$ exist and $$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0,0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0,0)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}(0,0,0)=0.$$

Let's assume now that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0,0)$ then $df(0,0,0):\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$ would be the zero map and thus $$f(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)-f(0,0,0)=o(\|(x,y,z)\|)$$ when $(x,y,z)$ goes to $(0,0,0)$.

But, $$\dfrac{f(x,x,x)}{\|(x,x,x)\|}=\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{(3x^2)^{3/2}}\underset{x\to 0}\sim \dfrac{1}{3^{3/2}}$$
which contradicts the Taylor expension of $f$ at $(0,0,0)$.
Hence $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0,0)$.